# Azure Data Factory - Unzip single file with multiple csv files being copied to different destinations

Tags: csv, zip, azure-data-factory

We are ingesting a zip file from blob storage with Azure Data Factory. Within this zipped file there are multiple csv files which need to be copied to Azure SQL tables.

For example, lets say zipped.zip contains Clients.csv, Accounts.csv, and Users.csv.  Each of these csv files will need to copied to a different destination table - dbo.Client, dbo.Account, and dbo.User.

It seems that I would need to use a Copy Activity to unzip and copy these files to a staging location, and from there copy those individual files to their respective tables.

Just want to confirm that there is not a different way to unzip and copy all in one action, without using a staging location?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thoughts are correct, there is no direct way without using a staging aspect as long as you are not writing any custom code logic and leveraging just the Copy activity

[image]

a somewhat similar thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/989436/unzip-only-csv-files-from-my-zip-file.html